# some confusions about Memory Alignment

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, struct, memory-alignment

```
#define     MCARD_CLS_TYPE_HD           1
#define     MCARD_SN_LEN                13

typedef struct mcard_ipc_list       
{                                   
    struct mcard_node *owner;

    struct
    {
        struct mcard_ipc_list *next;
        struct mcard_ipc_list *prev;
    } node;

    char sn_buf[MCARD_SN_LEN];  //13 byte

    struct len_str sn;          //8 byte                            
    struct mcard_smss smss[MCARD_CLS_TYPE_MIN + 1]; //16*3 byte
} _mcard_ipc_list;


struct mcard_smss           *smss = NULL;
struct mcard_node           *mnode = NULL;
...
smss = mnode->ipc_head.list->smss + MCARD_CLS_TYPE_HD;
```

the issue is that the data in `smss` is not correct in MFC application but ok in win32 console application!

I saw the **the address of variables** in the watch windows in VS2010.

the result of the win32 console application:

```
smss                            0x0068af61
&mnode->ipc_head.list->smss[1]  0x0068af61  
&mnode->ipc_head.list->smss[0]  0x0068af51 
mnode->ipc_head.list->sn_buf    0x005aaf3c
```

the result of the MFC application:

```
smss                            0x00b1ad54 
&mnode->ipc_head.list->smss[1]  0x00b1ad51 
&mnode->ipc_head.list->smss[0]  0x00b1ad41 
mnode->ipc_head.list->sn_buf    0x00b1ad2c
```

For MFC application, it's obvious that `smss` wa not equal to `&mnode->ipc_head.list->smss[1]` but has the offset `0x3` !

And we see that `mnode->ipc_head.list->sn_buf` occupy `13` bytes, not alligned!

i have solved the problem actually, and there is two methods:

(1)

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
#pragma pack(pop)
```

(2)

```
#define     MCARD_SN_LEN                16
```

However, i still confused about the **the difference** between win32 console application and MFC application when byte aligment needed!

**issue:**

1. **the distance** between `mnode->ipc_head.list->sn_buf` and  `&mnode->ipc_head.list->smss[0]` is `21` bytes 
   both in win32 console application and MFC application, not `24`bytes because `(13 + 3) + 8` means `24`! But why?
2. **the memory address** should be certain afer the variable defined, of course they have been aligned in memory afer the variable defined!  And `smss = mnode->ipc_head.list->smss + MCARD_CLS_TYPE_HD;` is just a **Assignment Statements**,
   why the result in MFC application is not `0x00b1ad51` but `0x00b1ad54`? And the phenomenon is reproducible!

So, if any one can help me out?

---

**update**:

um, i wrote a MFC demo to figure the 2nd issue out.

```
struct mcard_smss *smss = NULL;
smss = (struct mcard_smss *)0x00b1ad51;
```

However, the value of `smss` i saw in watch windows in vs2010 is not `0x00b1ad54` but `0x00b1ad51`!

Something changed and amazing! I don't know why

Comment: You will find `man offsetof` insightful. Suffice it to say, the compiler is free to determine the sizes of the fields within a struct and the padding bits can vary from implementation to implementation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i used `offsetof`, and get the offset of `mnode->ipc_head.list->sn` is  `25` in win32 console application,  `28` in MFC application. You help me  a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, since the compiler can set the size of the fields and padding within a *struct*, you can use `offsetof` macro (`stddef.h`) to determine the offset of a member within a macro:

```
size_t offsetof(type, member);
```

The man page for `offsetof` describes its use and provides an example.

> ```
> The macro offsetof() returns the offset of the field member from the
> start of the structure type.
>
> This  macro  is useful because the sizes of the fields that compose a 
> structure can vary across implementations, and compilers may insert 
> different numbers of padding bytes between fields.  Consequently, an 
> element's offset is not necessarily given by the sum of the sizes of 
> the previous elements.
>
> A compiler error will result if member is not aligned to a byte boundary
> (i.e., it is a bit field).
> ```

Glad it helped, let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: code in comment seems not good, i update the question.I appreciate your help

Comment: Cory, if you are talking about the `phello = (struct hello *)0x31;` then by my read, that should *segfault* due to assigning `phello` an address in the system reserved range. What comment are you talking about? You are saying you saw a change in the VS2010 watch window of `0x31` to `0x34`? What is `0x31`? The size of `struct hello`?

Comment: oh, it's my fault. I just want to imitate the same situation, i update right now.

Comment: OK, now I see what you are saying, good job on the edit. Let me first say, I'm not a VSXXXX user, but from a compiler standpoint, the padding inserted really is up to the compiler. If the alignment requirements differ within MFC and VS2010, then a 3 byte difference in padding is not strange at all. If the manner in which the fields are sized differs (e.g. `char a[5];` = 5-bytes, or `char a[5];` = 8-bytes), then that alone can easily account for a 3-byte difference. When you get to trying to find out why MFC does one thing, and why VS does another, you really need a MFC or VS specific forum.

Comment: hi, David.I just confused about the result of `smss` after the Assignment Statements.Then i i give the address `0x00b1ad51` to smss directly, but `smss` is not `0x00b1ad54` but `0x00b1ad51`, which differ with the result of my MFC application.

Comment: I saw what you were saying. I really think it is just a difference in either the alignment requirements or padding. Can you force alignment to a set amount? (e.g. 8-byte boundary, 16-bytes?) It can also be as simple as one padding before `a` and one padding after `a`. That's why we have `offsetof`.

Comment: oh, not that. The Win32 console application and MFC application both compiler, link,  run in VS2010.

Comment: maybe you are right, they may have a different alignment requirements.thanks

Comment: It can even come down to what the stack alignment requirements are. I suspect there is a difference depending on how you are compiling. Here is a link that does a fairly good job stepping through the issues [**Structure Member Alignment, Padding and Data Packing**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/)